# ajax call not hitting the controller when hosted in server

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

When running on my local machine, it works fine. But when hosted in a server, my ajax call didn't hit the controller and it gives me error 500 with message:

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..."

My ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Roster")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        Email: $('#txtUsername').val(),
        Password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
    },
    ...
)
```

in my Roster controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string tokenAddress = URI + "token";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tokenAddress);
            var account = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"username", model.Email },
                    {"password", model.Password },
                    {"grant_type", "password" }

                };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try monitoring your request in "Fiddler" this will help you identifying what exactly is the URL it is trying to access, and what data it tries to pass as parameter. There can be various reasons of 500. Fiddler is the best thing to start the investigations.

Comment: Actually it is working fine when using google postman, but I still don't get it, when hosted in the server, it gives me this error. I'm already stuck here for 2 days :(

Comment: Is `URI` an internal address on your own server, or something external / 3rd party? If external then it could be a firewall issue, DNS issue or IP-restriction-on-their-end issue.

Comment: URI is external address. Its just like this: https:xxx@x.com/. This where i hosted my api and front end web app.